# Notificação por push em uma rede local (caso sem internet)

Tags: java, android, json

Dei uma estudada nos serviços de **GCM** para envio e recebimento de notificações para o `android`, mas tenho a seguinte dúvida:

- Se eu estiver em um ambiente local, e o servidor de dados estiver no
  mesmo ambiente, existe alguma forma de eu trabalhar com as
  notificações automáticas toda vez que uma requisição for feita?

Por exemplo: Eu gravo dados novos por um `celular X`, e preciso enviar uma requisição automaticamente para um `celular Y` com os dados do registro. Consigo enviar e resgatar os dados por `JSON`, mas como faria para o celular detectar uma mudança na base de dados quando eu não tiver acesso a internet?

Existe alguma forma de substituir o GCM para estes casos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa ai é de uma aplicação rodando numa máquina local. No caso usando websockets
em Java ou algo similar.

`--------                ------------                -----------
|       |               |           |               |          |
| cel X | ----------->  | servidor  |  -----------> |  cel Y   |
|       | <-----------  |  websocket|  <----------- |          |
---------               -------------               ------------`

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/